# training output is not in the valid range by using CNN with LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification, conv-neural-network, lstm

I use keras with tf as the backend.

The goal of the simulation is attempting to use geo-spatial time series dataset to build a classifier. The target Y is labeled on -1, 0, 1 and 2, where -1 indicates the measured data at that grid point, 0 is meaning the data at good quality, 1 is middle quality and 2 is the worst.

Right now, i have two inputs. I have some atmospheric surface variables, such as wind, wind speed, and rain as one input. And , oceanic surface variables, such as sea surface temperature, and sea surface salinity as second input. The dimensions of all the datasets should be in, for example, (n_samples, n_timesteps, n_variables, n_xpoints: longitude, n_ypoints: latitude). The target dataset is in 3D dimensions like this: (n_samples, n_xpoints: longitude, n_ypoints: latitude).

In addition, all of the input variables are normalized by their value range. For example, the sea surface current velocity is normalized in the rage of (-1,1) from (-2, 2) [m/s], and the surface wind speed is normalized in the rage of (-1,1) from (-20,20) [m/s].

The model configuration is designed as described below.

```
def cnn():
   model = Sequential()
   model.add( Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu',
           data_format='channels_first', kernel_initializer='he_normal',
           name='conv1') )
   model.add( MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides = (2,2)))
   model.add( BatchNormalization() )

   model.add( Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu',
           kernel_initializer='he_normal', data_format='channels_first',
           name='conv2') )
   model.add( MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides = (2,2)))
   model.add( Dropout(0.2) )
   model.add( BatchNormalization() )
   model.add( Activation('relu') )

   model.add( MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides = (2,2)))
   model.add( Flatten() )
   model.add( Dense(128,activation='relu') )
   return model

def cnn2lstm(Input_shape, premo, name):
   branch_in = Input(shape=Input_shape, dtype='float32')
   model = TimeDistributed(premo)(branch_in)
   model = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, name=name+'_lstm1')(model)
   model = TimeDistributed(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))(model)
   model = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.3))(model)
   model = LSTM(256, return_sequences = True, name=name+'_lstm2')(model)
   model = Dense(101, activation='sigmoid')(model)
   model = Dropout(0.3)(model)
   return branch_in, model

atm_in, atm = cnn2lstm(Train_atm.shape[1:], cnn(),'atm')
ocn_in, ocn = cnn2lstm(Train_ocn.shape[1:], cnn(),'ocn')

#--- two inputs into one output
x = keras.layers.concatenate([atm,ocn],axis=1)   
x = LSTM(150,return_sequences=True)(x) 
x = Dropout(0.2)(x) 
x = LSTM(200,return_sequences=True)(x) 
x = Dropout(0.2)(x) 
x = LSTM(500)(x) 
x = Dense(1001,activation='relu')(x)   
x = Dense(2001,activation='relu')(x)   
x = Dense(2501,activation='tanh')(x) 
x = Dense(2701,activation='relu')(x) 
x = Dense(3355,activation='softmax')(x) 
x = Reshape((61,55),input_shape=(3355,))(x) 
model2 = Model(inputs=[atm_in, ocn_in, bio_in], outputs=x) 
plot_model(model2, show_shapes = True, to_file='model_way4_2.png') 
model2.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 

filepath='ways4_model02_best.hdf5'
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath,monitor='val_acc', verbose=1,save_best_only=True,mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
hist = model2.fit([Train_atm, Train_ocn, Train_bio], Train_Y, 
                        epochs=150, batch_size=3, validation_split=0.1, 
                        shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=0)           

scores = model2.evaluate([Train_atm, Train_ocn, Train_bio], Train_Y)
print("MODEL 2 %s: %.2f%%" % (model2.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

The evaluation scores here is mostly like 83% or higher. But the value of the output from `model2.predict` doesn't give me the valid range like my target dataset. In contrary, the model output give me the value from 0 to 1 (0,1) with a similar pattern as the target dataset shows.

Could anyone tell any big issue I have in my DL algorithm?

Comment: Hi im curious  why your last layer has `relu` as an activation function instead of a output activation function like tanh,sigmoid or softmax?

Comment: Last layer of CNN? I was just thinking the the last layer of the CNN is the input layer of LSTM, so that I want to use relu results instead of others.

Comment: I should mentioned this clear. The values in the target of my training sample is labeling to [-1, 0, 1, 2], which is indicating that -1: no data, 0, good quality data, normal quality, and bad quality in 1 and 2.

Comment: I think you should add the above information to the original question. Is you problem multi-class classification with labels as [-1, 0, 1, 2]?

Comment: Yes, its multiclassification. But my output is the float number between 0 and 1 now. I tried to modify the original question, but I failed.

Comment: This is confusing now. See if you can modify the question. If you have multi-class classification, you should do one-hot encoding and then use softmax activation.

Comment: agreed with Sata. Sigmoid works well sometimes as well. You should also convert your Y_labels to categorical outputs.

Comment: I see. I should use multi-class classification to work on this, or provides the "actual values" for regression by using rmse loss function.